# adding extra row to text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, csv, zip

I have a code that is something like that:

```
x = zip(sources,clist,RMSlist,residuelist)
name1 = string("sources")
name2 = string("clist")
name3 = string("RMSlist")
name4 = string("residuelist")
y = zip(name1,name2,name3,name4)
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
  writer.writerows(y) 
  writer.writerows(x)
```

My goal is to write each array in a column, but i want above that column a definition (a name) for it. Which was my attempt with the 4 names defined.

It Just for the sake of understanding the text file output better

Comment: `writer.writerow(["sources", "clist", "RMSlist", "residuelist"])`

Comment: it would be simpler if you would keep names as list `all_names = ["sources", "clist", "RMSlist", "residuelist"]` and then  you could use `for`-loop to create new list with `string(name)` and `writer.writerow[all_names]`

Comment: what do you try to save with `writerows(x)` ? If this are names/definitions then you should write it before `writerows(y)` to get it at the top.

Comment: now when I loop at you code I think all your problem is because you use `zip()` - you have to create normal list `y = ["sources", "clist", "RMSlist", "residuelist"]` without using `zip()` and write it `writerow(y)` without char `s` in word `writerow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is because you use `zip()` and `writerows` with char `s` at the end.

You should create normal list with names

```
names = ["sources", "clist", "RMSlist", "residuelist"]
```

and use `writerow` (without char `s` at the end) to write single row

```
writer.writerow(names)  # without char `s`
```

---

**BTW:** Instead of name `names` (which may means many objects) you can use name `header` which means single object.

---

```
header = ["sources", "clist", "RMSlist", "residuelist"]

rows = zip(sources, clist, RMSlist, residuelist)

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
  writer.writerow(header)  # without char `s` to write one row
  writer.writerows(rows)   # with char `s` to write many rows
```

Comment: thanks for the help, didn't pay attention to the s at the end!